# Whats the difference beetween deno install and deno compile?

Tags: deno

If I do `deno --help` it shows:

- compile = Compile the script into a self-contained executable
- install = Install script as an executable

What's the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

| Command | Output | Self contained <sup>1</sup> | Deno runtime integrated <sup>2</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `compile` | binary | y | y |
| `install` | script (shell / `.bat`) | n | n |
| `bundle` | `.js` | y | n |

<sup>1</sup> self contained := includes local and remote dependencies / scripts, single file

<sup>2</sup> integrated := no *separate* runtime is needed

Comment: So if I want to create a script executable for others to use I would want to use compile right?

Comment: It depends - the `compile`d  sources are considerably larger than the pure script file with `bundle` (devs intend to work on reducing the binary size in later revisions). So if the script size doesn't matter / the client does not have a deno runtime / you want to ensure a certain version / it should be executed as simple as possible / code "transparency" is not important for the client, take `compile`, otherwise `bundle`.

Comment: When I install a TS/JS script will deno also move my script to the same location as the output shell / batch or even embed the TS/JS script into it?