# Making a Deno Script globally available

Tags: bash, path, deno

Have built myself a CLI tool for my more generic projects using Deno. It's useful, does the stuff I need it to do. However, I'm looking into achieving something similar to `npm install -g <my-git-repo>` but with Deno.

I understand I could easily create a `~/.myDeno` with a bash script and adding `export PATH=$PATH:~/.myDeno` but was wondering if there was a proper process to follow to achieve this with Deno. As I have thus far been unable to find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `deno install` or `deno compile` to create executables from Deno code.

`deno install` will install your CLI tool in `$HOME/.deno/bin` or a custom directory when you set the DENO_INSTALL_ROOT environment variable.

`deno_compile` will create a self-contained binary including the runtime and dependencies, as was answered [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65715026/whats-the-difference-beetween-deno-install-and-deno-compile). It would make the executable more stand-alone but it increases the size of the compiled source.

It's up to you which one you prefer, but they can both work to execute a Deno module 'globally'

Comment: Thanks for this, it's purely for a small SS script to clone deno modules down from private GitLab repo's using deploy tokens as GitLab doesn't support DENO_AUTH_TOKEN dependency pulling yet.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else `deno install <dir|git repo>` installs it the `.deno` folder in your home directory and provides an PATH amendment you need to add to your bash profile.